# Adding list to cell in dataframe base on 2 conditions to delete elements in each list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have two columns in a data frame, the first one with a list of numbers in each cell and the second one with a list of letters in each cell.
I want to create two more columns considering the following conditions:

When a value in column "A" is < 1 this value is going to stay in the list and the other ones are gonna be deleted, with this condition the letter that is at the same index as the number in column "A"

[image: Table]

Output:

[image]

I wasn´t able to do this within the datframe so I try to create a list of list and then add'em as a columns but this works fine if I use only a list but for the columns is not working.

I would like some advice for this.

```
big_a = []
big_b = []

new_list_a = []
new_list_b = []
for a, b in zip(x['COLUMN_A'], x['COLUMN_B']):
    if a < 1:
        new_list_a = []
        new_list_b = []
        new_list_a.append(a)
        new_list_b.append(b)   
        big_a.append(new_list_a)
        big_b.append(new_list_b)
```

This gives me the following error:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 

def process(row):
    np_A = np.array(row.COLUMN_A)
    np_B = np.array(row.COLUMN_B)
        
    return np_A[np_A<1], np_B[np_A<1] 
    
df[["NEW_A","NEW_B"]] = df.apply(lambda row: pd.Series(process(row)), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Create the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [[0.99, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 0.25, 0.87]],
    'B': [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
})

# Convert the lists to numpy ndarray
df = df.applymap(np.asarray)

# Explode the dataframe
df = df.reset_index().apply(pd.Series.explode).set_index(['index', 'B'])

# Filter for rows whose value for column 'A' is less than 1
df = df[df < 1].dropna().reset_index().groupby('index').agg(list)
```

The initial DataFrame is

```
    A                    B
0   [0.99, 1.0, 1.0]    [a, b, c]
1   [1.0, 1.0, 1.0]     [a, b, c]
2   [1.0, 0.25, 0.87]   [a, b, c]
```

The final DataFrame will look like:

```
      B     A
index       
0    [a]    [0.99]
2    [b, c] [0.25, 0.87]
```

Notes:

Find more details about pandas explode [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html).